# C++ vs D - Algorithm Optimization/Conversion (Using vectors/arrays)

Tags: c++, optimization, d

OK, I've been playing with D for a while (and been *in love* with its expressive power and simplicity, to be honest). However, since I'm still new to D, I'm facing a few issues.

Let's take the following example. All the following program does is to take numbers in the 0..10000000 (fairly big one, for benchmarking purposes) and for each one of them return a vector/array with the positions of bits set (in binary).

**E.g.**

```
4 = 100(2) => [ 2 ]
5 = 101(2) => [ 0, 2 ]
6 = 110(2) => [ 1, 2 ]
7 = 111(2) => [ 0, 1, 2]

And so on...
```

---

Now here's my **C++ code** (no vector `reserve` etc being used) :

```
// bits.cpp

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

vector<unsigned int> bitsSet(unsigned long long bitboard)
{
    unsigned int n;
    vector<unsigned int> res;

    for (n = 0; bitboard != 0; n++, bitboard &= (bitboard - 1))
    {
        res.push_back(log2(bitboard & ~(bitboard-1)));
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    for (int k=0; k<10000000; k++)
    {
        vector<unsigned int> res = bitsSet(k);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's my **D code** :

```
// bits.d

import std.stdio;
import std.math;

int[] bitsSet(ulong bitboard)
{
    int[] res;

    for (int n=0; bitboard!=0; n++, bitboard&=(bitboard-1))
        res ~= cast(int)log2(bitboard & ~(bitboard-1));

    return res;
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    for (ulong k=0; k<10000000; k++)
    {
        int[] bits = bitsSet(k);
    }
}
```

---

Now, given that the 2 pieces of code are compiled with `g++ bits.cpp -o cbits` (or `clang++ bits.cpp -o cbits`) and `dmd bits.d -ofdbits`, respectively, these are my benchmark results, using `time` (on Mac OS X 10.8.2) :

**For C++ :**

```
time ./cbits

real    0m19.742s
user    0m19.722s
sys 0m0.012s
```

**For D :**

```
time ./dbits

real    0m14.914s
user    0m14.891s
sys 0m0.017s
```

---

This looks OK. (with D being - for me - noticeably faster).

**NOTE :**

Now, if I try to use something like `res.reserve(64);` in my C++ `bitsSet` function, though, time drops to around 7s.... which *IS* significantly faster. Tried something like `res.length = 64;` (in my D code), time dropped to around 11s (though slower than C++), but I'm not sure if the result is the same...

---

**What further optimizations would you suggest for my D code, so that it's *at least* as fast as my C++ code?**

---

#### Results with Compiler Optimization flags :

With `clang++ bits.cpp -O3 -o cbits`

```
time ./cbits

real    0m8.994s
user    0m8.986s
sys 0m0.006s
```

With `dmd bits.d -O -release -inline -m64 -ofdbits`

```
time ./bitsd

real    0m14.083s
user    0m14.034s
sys 0m0.014s
```

Which looks pretty amazing (or bizarre). Clang managed to go from 19 to 8 seconds, while D optimization did nothing???

**EDIT :** So, is there no hope that my D code will run as fast as it's C++ counterpart?

Comment: What further optimisations? What about... `-O3`?

Comment: I could suggest compiling with optimizations on (`-O2` or `-Os`) for the C++ code.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Well, I was basically talking about optimizations in the code. (I'll post my results with `-O3` - and their D analogues - right now)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon optimisations in the code are a pointless exercise if you request of the compiler to make a slow program.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Have a look at my posted results. Any additional advice (on the D code/compilation) would be more than welcome.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Is this actually true? For example the Linux kernel is rarely built with -O3. From my C++ experience the compiler will often emit 2 version, one that is optimized and one that is  not optimized when it should only omit the optimized version, this is a problem because it may be too strict when choosing when to use the optimized version.

Comment: I would be more than happy to know why *this* question has received 3 downvotes and 2 close votes. I'm really curious... (I know D may sound obscure to most people, but that's definitely not a reason to downvote... without any explanation)...

Comment: If you're looking for ways to improve the D code, a better place is codereview IMO. If you're asking to compare the results, it's not really constructive.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon sorry, I only know C++ :) I would probably get rid of log2, but from there I have no idea.

Comment: *"`cast(int)log2`"* - Looks like you're using some floating point log2 in *D* (don't now about *C++*, since you seem to be using your own `"math.h"`, probably with an int log2?). If that's the case then better luck next time.

Comment: The `n` variable seems to be completely unused in both examples, also, shouldn't `6` be `110(2) => [ 1, 2 ]`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It's OK! :-) As far as the `log2` in the `bitsSet` function, I've ran *countless* of test for this specific function and this is by far the fastest implementation (at least in C++). I'm using it in a Chess engine project of mine (which I'm currently rewriting in D), so speed is crucial...

Comment: *"Here is a code in one language and a similar code in another, why is one faster than the other? By the way I left out any compiler optimizations to make all time measurements obsolete"* - Better luck next time with this, too.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon But you're sure this standard library `log2` in *D* also works on integers? I'm asking because of the cast (and I'm not sure *D* even has an integer log2). For a simple yet fast integer implementation see [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html). But then again I might be wrong and *D* really provides and optimized integer log2.

Comment: @Mankarse Your observation about `n` is correct (just a leftover from previous implementations) and so is your observation about the `110(2)` example (just a typo; which I fixed)

Comment: The reason this has so many down and close votes is because it is a bad question that does not belong here. There is no set problem to which a correction can be provided, you simply have an open ended X is better then Y. You have ignorantly attempted to compare languages as if they equal, despite the fact they have different was of working.

Comment: @ChristianRau This *may* be a great catch. I'm quite new to D, so this could actually be an issue (I'm currently looking into that, and I'll let you know). As for compiler optimizations, I just decided to put them aside, just in order to compare the different version (as they are) and then with different flags, etc. (You may currently see the results *with* the appropriate optimization flags at the end of the original post).

Comment: @thecoshman The question is as clear as that : is there anything wrong in the D counterpart? (or phrased this way : "am I missing something, or is it just that we're dealing with a compiler generating slower binaries?"). Maybe it's just me, but I still can't see what's so debateable about it. (I suppose if I was asking for advice for conversion to Java code, the downvotes would be quite fewer...)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon a better question would then be - here's my D code, how do I make it faster? And, even so, a better place would be codereview. The relevant SO part would be, I guess, "why is the log function so slow in D?". I see absolutely no reason for dragging C++ into this.

Comment: @ChristianRau Just tried "eliminating" the `cast(int)` part as well as D's `log2` (by replacing it with an `extern (C)` call to `log2`). There *is* some speed gain. But it still runs like 4 seconds slower - quite disappointing...

Comment: I am pretty sure that C++ program is that fast because it throw away whole loop. I'm even thinking why it take it 3s to execute. You should display the result of the function.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon *"by replacing it with an `extern (C)` call to `log2`"* - But I hope not the `log2` of the C standard library, sicne that works on floats, too. What function do you use in C++, if that is also the builtin `log2`, then Ok, both versions would at least be equal (even if using a float log2 for integer computation was rubbish in the first place).

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier *"pretty sure"* - Wouldn't that make the C++ program run in nearly no time, instead of just double the speed of the D version (and still 9 seconds)?

Comment: Not sure about difference, but try using `gdc` for better performance. By the way you can use `res.reserve(64)` in D too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about: using `res.length = 64;` and then in your loop replace

```
res ~= cast(int)log2(bitboard & ~(bitboard-1));
```

by:

```
res[n] = cast(int)log2(bitboard & ~(bitboard-1));
```

But to be honest this type of code will be completely dominated by allocations, which is not entirely interesting as a language benchmark. Try to reuse the same array instead.

And there is much faster ways of locating bits (see `core.bitop`).

tl;dr you're optimizing a slow program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm currently looking into it. (Actually I've tried what you suggest with `res.length` but without any great difference). One question : I knew about `std.intrinsic`. However, I'm a bit perplexed : Is it working with `ulong`s (64-bit unsigned ints)? (this *has* to be able to work with 64-bit ints, otherwise it's not of much use to me...)

Comment: *"you're optimizing a slow program"* - Better than optimizing a fast one, isn't it? No, really +1 ;)

Comment: @ponce Just trying to figure out what's going on : is `std.intrinsic` still supported? (`dmd` and `ldmd2` both give me errors, and I definitely cannot find the `std/intrinsic.d` file in D's current release. (Perhaps it's been deprecated since D v1.0?)

Comment: My bad, `std.intrinsic` is now called `core.bitop`. bsf makes you avoid a call to log2.